# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) Which VS Project Type / NuGet Format?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, csproj

In Visual Studio projects used to have the csproj extension. NuGet used to have a packages.config file associated with the project for configuring NuGet packages. Eventually, this was changed to project.json. Then, when ASP.NET Core came in, Microsoft created a new project format called xproj. This project format was fraught with problems and many people at Microsoft said they were going to dump the format. They also mentioned that they were planning on dumping project.json as well.

My current ASP.NET Core project is csproj file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

And, I am still using packages.config for NuGet.

I just want to know, which project format should we be using as we move in to the future? Is it csproj? Will we still be using project.json? What do I need to do to make sure I have upgraded to the most modern project type, and NuGet format in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

.csproj file is the right way to go. Resources on the topic:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/

> There are many of you that have already adopted .NET Core with the existing project.json project format and build system. Us, too! **We built a migration tool that migrates project.json project files to csproj.**

https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/project-json-replaced-by-csproj

Comment: I'm glad that project.json is getting dumped finally, but is there a tool to upgrade from packages.config to csproj 15? If not, is there an intermediate tool to migrate from packages.config to project.json, and then to csproj 15?

Comment: Never done that but you can follow this link: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Converting-a-csproj-from-package.config-to-project.json

Answer (score 1):

Use Visual Studio 2017 and the new MSBuild 15.x which gives you a better csproj file format.

Comment: This sounds about right. How do I upgrade from csproj v.14 with packages.config -> csproj v.15?

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper when you open it in VS2017 the upgrade wizard might appear. Even if it doesn't, you can manually edit your csproj to be MSBuild 15 compatible, and move all projects.json elements into it. There is a learning curve, but it is possible.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not using project.json. I'm using packages.config. Are you saying that I will probably need to manually move all the NuGet references in by hand?

Comment: If I were you, I will try first. Even if manual upgrade is needed, it would be quite easy to follow, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in Visual Studio 2015 and working on .Net core projects then you will be using .xproj and package.json.
While this is true with Visual Studio 2015, in Visual Studio 2017 Microsoft changed .xproj to .csproj which is MSBuild compatible project file format. All dependencies to project are stored in .csproj file itself rather having them in separate package.json file.
If you are starting new project and have luxury to use VS2017 then you will be using .csproj. You can not create .xproj file with VS2017 and will not be able to create .csproj (.Net Core based) project in VS2015.

Comment: As mentioned, I am using csproj and packages.config. I'm not using the xproj format.